# Can't get access to $root in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my application I have a root page. In this root page I include `Navbar component` from which I try to get access to variable named `currentRoute`.
My `index.js`, where I defined `currentRoute`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import routes from './routes';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentRoute: window.location.pathname,
    },
    computed: {
        ViewComponent () {
            return routes[this.currentRoute] || routes.NotFound;
        }
    },
    render (h) {
        return h(this.ViewComponent)
    }
});

window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
    app.currentRoute = window.location.pathname;
});
```

I have `home.vue` which is default route and where I included a component named `Navbar` where I try to get access to `currentRoute` and which looks like:

```
<template lang="jade">
.navbar
    .row
        .col.text-center
            a.post-outline.navbar--icon(href='/new-post', @click="newPost")
        .col.text-center
            i.email-outline.navbar--icon
        .col.text-center
            i.person-outline.navbar--icon
</template>

<script>
import routes from '../../routes';
export default {
    props: {
        href: String,
        required: true
    },
    computed: {
        isActive () {
            return this.href === this.$root.currentRoute
        }
    },
    methods: {
        newPost: event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            this.$root.currentRoute = this.href;

            window.history.pushState(
              null,
              routes[this.href],
              this.href
            )
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

My routes.js:

```
import NotFound from './pages/404.vue';
import Home from './pages/home.vue';
const NewPost = { template: '<p>new post page</p>' }

export default {
    '/': Home,
    '/new-post': NewPost
}
```

Everything works fine but `this.$root` is undefined. Why and where is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `newPost()` uses the ES6/2015 arrow function syntax `(() => {})`, which binds `this` to the parent context. In your case, the parent context is the module and not the Vue instance, so it doesn't have a reference to the `$root`.

You need to use to either declare the function normally:

```
newPost: function(event) { }
```

Or, you can use the ES6/2015 shorthand:

```
newPost(event) { }
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In vue.js, data is passed from parent to children via props. It's passed by reference so if you change it in the child, it would affect the parent state.